# Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku. But it is not on the Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite, heroku, deployment

In my Gemfile I commented the line `gem 'sqlite3'` and I ran `bundler update` and `bundler install` and `git add .` and `git commit -m "..."`. But the error keeps popping up when I try `git push heroku master`.

### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.2'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
  # Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'devise'
```

### Errors

```
Counting objects: 85, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (70/70), done.
Writing objects: 100% (85/85), 20.12 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 85 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.13.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.7) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.14.6). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Installing i18n 0.8.1
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
remote:        Installing rake 12.0.0
remote:        Installing minitest 5.10.1
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.3
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Installing rack 2.0.1
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.0.0 with native extensions
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.2
remote:        Installing arel 7.1.4
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Installing method_source 0.8.2
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.4
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Using bundler 1.13.7
remote:        Installing puma 3.8.2 with native extensions
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.23
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.7
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.3.13 with native extensions
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.3
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.7.1 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.1
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.6.5 with native extensions
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.2.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Installing activesupport 5.0.2
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_c7d63c20559c9c0f3d363c105f864362/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/ext/sqlite3
remote:        /tmp/build_c7d63c20559c9c0f3d363c105f864362/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby -r
remote:        ./siteconf20170519-225-1fsl87m.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_c7d63c20559c9c0f3d363c105f864362/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-config
remote:        --without-sqlite3-config
remote:        --with-pkg-config
remote:        --without-pkg-config
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
remote:        be found here:
remote:        /tmp/build_c7d63c20559c9c0f3d363c105f864362/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/mkmf.log
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_c7d63c20559c9c0f3d363c105f864362/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13
remote:        for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_c7d63c20559c9c0f3d363c105f864362/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:        Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.13.7) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.14.6). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
remote:        Installing i18n 0.8.1
remote:        Installing concurrent-ruby 1.0.5
remote:        Installing rake 12.0.0
remote:        Installing minitest 5.10.1
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.3
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Installing rack 2.0.1
remote:        Installing nio4r 2.0.0 with native extensions
remote:        Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.2
remote:        Installing arel 7.1.4
remote:        Installing mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Installing execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
remote:        Installing method_source 0.8.2
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.4
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Using bundler 1.13.7
remote:        Installing puma 3.8.2 with native extensions
remote:        Installing sass 3.4.23
remote:        Installing tilt 2.0.7
remote:        Installing sqlite3 1.3.13 with native extensions
remote:        Installing turbolinks-source 5.0.0
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.3
remote:        Installing nokogiri 1.7.1 with native extensions
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing sprockets 3.7.1
remote:        Installing websocket-driver 0.6.5 with native extensions
remote:        Installing mime-types 3.1
remote:        Installing uglifier 3.2.0
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Installing activesupport 5.0.2
remote:        Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        current directory:
remote:        /tmp/build_c7d63c20559c9c0f3d363c105f864362/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13/ext/sqlite3
remote:        /tmp/build_c7d63c20559c9c0f3d363c105f864362/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/bin/ruby -r
remote:        ./siteconf20170519-225-1fsl87m.rb extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'brew install sqlite3',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_c7d63c20559c9c0f3d363c105f864362/vendor/ruby-2.3.4/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
remote:        --with-sqlite3-config
remote:        --without-sqlite3-config
remote:        --with-pkg-config
remote:        --without-pkg-config
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
remote:        
remote:        To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can
remote:        be found here:
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_c7d63c20559c9c0f3d363c105f864362/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/mkmf.log
remote:        
remote:        extconf failed, exit code 1
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in
remote:        /tmp/build_c7d63c20559c9c0f3d363c105f864362/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.13
remote:        for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to
remote:        /tmp/build_c7d63c20559c9c0f3d363c105f864362/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/sqlite3-1.3.13/gem_make.out
remote:        
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.13), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to osty.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/osty.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/osty.git'
```

What do I have to do?

Comment: Post your gemfile. Is it possible that you commented out sqlite3 under dev or test but left it intact under production?

Comment: Post you error also.

Comment: also you need to add 'pg' gem into production group

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay I did that too but the same error still appears.

Comment: do one thing delete your gemfile.lock and reinstall all gem then push to heroku with gemfile.lock this trick might work

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay Still not work.

Comment: @MarsAtomic It is not. I posted my Gemfile now.

Comment: @MayurShah Now I posted the errors too.

Comment: Please post your gemfile.lock. We're looking for another gem that might have sqlite3 as a dependency, since your gemfile looks fine.

Answer (score 3):

Heroku can't install the sqlite3 gem, for whatever reason

You can do following change in gem file

In your Gemfile

```
gem 'sqlite3' (if you have)
```

to

```
gem 'pg'
```

Note: You will have to run

```
git add .
git commit
```

before running

```
git push heroku master
```

If you want to use `sqlite` for `development` and `test` and then `postgresql` for Heroku, use following config.

```
group :development, :test do 
   gem 'sqlite3'    #gem to use in development-test environment
end

group :production do 
  gem 'pg'         #gem to use in production environment
end
```

Heroku will use pg gem since heroku run your application in production enviroment

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar error when I added my .bundle to my git repo for "convenience", which took me a bit to debug, but after removing it, the error went away.